# Find the intervals on which $f(x)=x + \frac{1}{x}$ is monotonically increasing and decreasing

Tags: functions, proof-verification

Given $f(x) = x + \frac{1}{x}$. Graphically, the function looks like this: https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+y+%3D+x+%2B+1%2Fx.

I have taken the first derivative and found that $f'(x)=1 - \frac{1}{x^{2}}$.

I've also found the turning points of the function by setting $f'(x)=0$. They are $x=\pm 1$.

I've also played with the signs of the first derivative, that is, figuring out when it's positive or negative.

So are the intervals $(-\infty, -1) \cup (1, \infty)$ on which $f$ is increasing and $(-1, 0) \cup (0, 1)$ on which $f$ is decreasing?

Comment: It looks like you've already answered your own question...

Comment: $f$ is increasing on the interval  $A=(-\infty,-1]$ and on the interval $B=[1,\infty) .$  Also $f $ is increasing  on the set  $A\cup B,$ which is NOT an interval, because (i)  $f $ is  increasing on $A$ and on $ B,$ and (ii) $\forall x\in A \forall y\in B\;(x<y\land f(x)<f(y))$.....Consider $g(x)=x+2$ for $x\leq -1,\; g(x)=-x$ for $|x|\leq 1,\; g(x)=x-2$ for $x\geq 1.$  Then $g$ is increasing on $A=(-\infty,-1]$ and on $B=[1,\infty)$ but $g$ is not increasing on $A\cup B$ because $g(-1)>g(1).$

Comment: @DanielWainfleet  Why do you say it is both increasing and decreasing at the points x = 1 and x = -1.  the derivative is 0 on those points and I'd say it is neither increasing nor decreasing on the points.

Comment: $f$ is increasing on a set $D$ iff $f(x)\leq f(y)$ whenever $x,y\in D$ and $x<y. $ .(If we replace $f(x)\le f(y)$ by $f(x)<f(y)$ in that sentence we say  $f$ is strictly increasing. ) This is not the same thing as saying that $f$ is increasing at each point of $D$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You did not specify open intervals.

$f$ is increasing  on $(-\infty,-1]$ and on $[1,\infty).$

$f$ is decreasing on [-1,0) and on (0,1].

A union of a pair of intervals is not necessarily an interval. $(-\infty,-1)\cup (1,\infty)$ is not an interval.

$f$ is NOT  decreasing on the (non-interval ) set $C=(-1,0)\cup (0,1)$ because $-1/2$ and $+1/2$ belong to $C$ with $-1/2<+1/2$ and $f(-1/2)<f(+1/2).$